# save static image same way like uploaded image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, upload

I'm developing a set of tools in JavaScript and I'm having a trouble with saving static images. First of all I've created uploader to upload images that are later saved in `upload/` directory.

Uploaded images (file) are sent to server like this:

```
$.ajax({
        data: { file: e.dataTransfer.file },
        url: 'server/uploading_files.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
           ....
       }
});
```

And I would love to do the same with images where I have only path to them -> statically save them.
Problem is in structure I'm sending to server side. Because `e.dataTransfer.file` looks like this:

```
FileList{0: File, length: 1}
   0: File
      lastModified:1441797733000
      lastModifiedDate:Wed Sep 09 2015 13:22:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)
      name:"sp_dom1.jpg"
      size:563989
      type:"image/jpeg"
      webkitRelativePath:""
```

And when I want to save static image I have only path without any structure.

Is there any solution how to crate the same structure for uploading static images? I don't want to use 2 different .php files for save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `XMLHttpRequest`, with `responseType` set to `"blob"`, `new File()` constructor available at chrome / chromium 38+

```js
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
var pathToImage = "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "blob";
request.open("GET", pathToImage);
request.onload = function() {
  var file = this.response;
  dfd.resolve(
    new File([file]
             , file.name 
               || "img-" + new Date().getTime() 
                  + "." + file.type.split("/")[1]
             , {
                 type: file.type
               }
    )
  )
};
request.send();

dfd.then(function(data) {
  // do stuff with `data`
  // i.e.g.;
  // $.ajax({
  //      data: { file: data },
  //      url: 'server/uploading_files.php',
  //      method: 'POST',
  //      success: function (response) {
  //         ....
  //     }
  // });
  console.log(data);
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = function() {
    $("body").append(this)
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: @PetrBečka `File` constructor is also available at firefox 44+, opera 36+ see http://caniuse.com/#search=File